# MYSQL data from vertical to horizontal PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have Database like this :

```
+----------+------------+-------+
| TIME     | Date       | A0    |
+----------+------------+-------+
| 17:00:00 | 2015-06-23 | 100   |
| 17:05:00 | 2015-06-23 | 120   |
| 17:10:00 | 2015-06-23 | 200   |
| 17:00:00 | 2015-06-24 | 200   |
| 17:05:00 | 2015-06-24 | 190   |
| 17:10:00 | 2015-06-24 | 200   |
| 17:00:00 | 2015-06-25 | 90    |
| 17:05:00 | 2015-06-25 | 100   |
| 17:10:00 | 2015-06-25 | 200   |
| .        | .          | .     |
| .        | .          | .     |
| .        | .          | .     |
| .        | .          | .     |
| TIME(n)  | Date(n)    | A0(n) |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

I want it to be shown like this at my homepage :

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|  TIME    | 2015-06-23 | 2015-06-24 | 2015-06-25 | .....Date(n) |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
| 17:00:00 | 100        | 200        | 90         | .....A0(n)   |
| 17:05:00 | 120        | 190        | 100        | .....A0(n)   |
| Time(n)  | A0(n)      | A0(n)      | A0(n)      | .....A0(n)   |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

I use `(n)` because my homepage let me select any point of date and time and show A0 value at that date and time.

Should I use group concat, for each, or another method?

Comment: For your information, the operation you look for is called "pivoting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps.

```
<?php

/*
$rows = array(
array('time' => '17:00:00', 'date' => '2015-06-23', 'a0' => 100),
array('time' => '17:05:00', 'date' => '2015-06-23', 'a0' => 120),
array('time' => '17:00:00', 'date' => '2015-06-24', 'a0' => 10),
array('time' => '17:05:00', 'date' => '2015-06-24', 'a0' => 20),
array('time' => '17:00:00', 'date' => '2015-06-25', 'a0' => 10),
array('time' => '17:05:00', 'date' => '2015-06-26', 'a0' => 20),
);*/

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database"); // connecting

$result = $db->query("SELECT time, date, a0 FROM define_your_table_name_here"); // query-in database

$data = array();
$dates = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // fetching result
    if(!isset($data[$row['time']])) {
        $data[$row['time']] = array();
    }    

    if(!isset($data[$row['time']][$row['date']])) {
        $data[$row['time']][$row['date']] = array();
    }    

    if(!in_array($row['date'], $dates)) {
        $dates[] = $row['date'];
    }

    $data[$row['time']][$row['date']] = $row['a0'];
}
?>

<table border="1">
<thead>
    <th>TIME</th>

    <?php foreach($dates AS $date) : ?>
        <th><?=$date?></th>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <?php foreach($data AS $time => $entries) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$time?></td>

        <?php foreach($dates AS $date) : ?>
            <td><?=(isset($data[$time][$date])?$data[$time][$date]:'')?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: when i execute it, i get error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Latihan\TES TABEL.php on line 5. What would solve this ?

Comment: ops... I've forgotten to terminate first array with comma after ] (on line: 4)

Comment: also, is that was hard to find 4 and 5-th line and fix it? why You PHP developers (not all of) are so lazy? (:

Comment: in Your question You get rows from database, so You've to fetch rows from database, into rows array.

Comment: ok first of all, i am really sorry because i am really new to this PHP world and no one can teach me at a time. So, I really need your help. When i give comma, i got a message that arse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Latihan\TES TABEL.php on line 41. So, i change that with <?php instead of <?, and apply it to other line. But i get only TIME text alone. What should i do ? I really appreciate your help

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your replies, but there is a little problem that i cant solve. First of all, i change symbol [] after the array to () so it can work. Time and date displayed correctly, but a0 wont showed up, instead i get this message at a0 space : Notice: Undefined variable: a0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Latihan\TES TABEL.php on line 43

Comment: Thank you soooooo much. Thought i will be more pleased if you insert the mysqli_fetch too but thats okay i will try to figure it out myself. Once again thank you I really appreciate it

Comment: Ok I try to fetch it myself but i cant do it. Can you please help me one more time ?